# How to delete photos/videos on Samsung but make sure they are not deleted on Amazon Photos?

Tags: backup, factory-reset, cloud

I just backed up all my photos/videos to Amazon Photos but have been reading different blogs that say do not delete your photos from the gallery or it will be deleted from your Amazon Photos. I just bought a new phone. Will the factory reset delete my backup to Amazon Photos?

Comment: Can you link the places you saw say they will be deleted?

Comment: I don't know for Amazon Photos, but for Google Photos, when you delete the image from *within the app*, then it will also delete the image in the cloud (because Google Photos is a cloud *sync* service, not really a cloud backup service). However, if the image has been synced ("backup") but deleted from another app, then it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I hardly doubt any backup cloud service would delete your backup files if you delete them in the phone, so I wonder what are those blogs you've come across?
you could do a test, try deleting couple of photos, while keeping it safe, like copying to another folder. Then, you can check amazon photos and see it that photo is still there.
Also, Google Photos (since you already need to have google account for your Samsung phone) is a nice photo/video sync/backup app. You can use more than one app, there are plenty of cloud apps that offer even 1TB free space, and once uploaded, those photos stay there "in the cloud". Just be careful when you want to organize files and folders in the cloud, so you don't end up deleting backed up files that have already been removed from your phone. But I've never heard that backup files are deleted once originals are deleted. It usually deletes photos and videos AFTER you back them up.